# SwiftUI: Multiplatform app swiftui unexpected platform condition

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui-list, xcode12beta6

I'm trying to implement a list in a Multiplatform implementation here is my implementation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header"), footer: Text("Footer")){
                ForEach(0..<5){
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .tag($0)
                }
            }
            #if os(iOS)
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

But on this line:

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unexpected platform condition (expected `os`, `arch`, or `swift`)
```

Any of you knows a way around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: @Paulw11, correct that is the reason I add `#if os(iOS)`. Do I need to add an alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't like conditional compilation code very much.

Try something like this:

```
#if os(macOS)
typealias MyListStyle = PlainListStyle
#else
typealias MyListStyle = GroupedListStyle
#endif
...
SomeView {}
.listStyle(MyListStyle())
```

Or

```
func myListStyle() -> some View {
    #if os(macOS)
    return listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    #else
    return listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    #endif
}
...
SomeView {}
.myListStyle()
```

You can also use a variation of the `func` with a returned `self` for modifiers that aren't appropriate.  I also used it to make `.environment` conditional.

Comment: I implemented your solution but I'm getting and error in this line `Section(header`, error: `Instance method "listStyle" requieres that some view conform to ListStyle`

Comment: You can only apply `.listStyle` to a `List` or maybe a form or a stack.
It probably doesn't work on a `Section`.  That's what the compiler is telling you.
SwiftUI often has cryptic error messages, but this one is very plain and specific.